# Getting an error when using urllib.request.urlopen() on Python 3.2.1

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

I am using urllib.request to open a page source with Python 3.2.1, but I am getting an error saying `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable`. Please find the code and error below.

### Code

```
import re
import urllib.request

html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html").read().decode()

print (html)
```

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "I:/Private/nabm/python/python_challenge/python_challenge_2.py", line 4, in <module>
    html = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html").read().decode()
  File "C:\appl\Python\3.2.1\lib\urllib\request.py", line 138, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\appl\Python\3.2.1\lib\urllib\request.py", line 375, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\appl\Python\3.2.1\lib\urllib\request.py", line 487, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\appl\Python\3.2.1\lib\urllib\request.py", line 413, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\appl\Python\3.2.1\lib\urllib\request.py", line 347, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\appl\Python\3.2.1\lib\urllib\request.py", line 495, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 503: Service Unavailable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Could anyone see what could be causing this error?

Comment: Check your connection. This doesn't reproduce on my system: `urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html").status ; 200`

Comment: You code work. You can try with an other lib like `request` is similar to urllib `request.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/ocr.html').content`. If it's don't work too, maybe you have firewall who block you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP error 503 means that the server wasn't able to respond at that moment, either due to overload or because it refused your connection. In other words, there is nothing you can change in your code to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue with some URLs and providing a header helped. When I looked more into it I found out that the servers sometimes identify that a bot is trying to access the website and so to prevent it they give a fake a connection  error.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request
header = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.159 Safari/537.36."}
req = Request("url", headers=header)

response = urlopen(req, timeout=60)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while from the date. But I will post how I dealt with the "HTTP Error 503" in case it might help someone else.
First of all, I did put request.urlretrieve(...) into a try block to catch the error. 
In my case it is true that the server I tried to access needs time to handle the requests. (The server I accessed is not Amazon.com or that sort which were said to prevent programs to access their content.)
Withing the try block, in the case the exception occurs, I made the program to wait for 20 seconds using time.sleep(20). This enables my program to complete.